# Who is eating my \n

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I send this json to my controller (as seen in my webrick log):

```
{\"repeatEveryYear\":\"TRUE\",\"scheduleTime\":\"2010-09-09T16:11:46Z\",\"message\":\"Hello World\n\nFirst test\"}
```

I dont know where all the escaping comes from, it is not something I add, and it seems rails eats it just fine?

My problem is that the second \n gets eaten some where in the process. Here is my controller that reads the json:

```
class SchedulesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @schedule = Schedules.new.from_json(params[:schedule])
    @schedule.save
    render :json => "ok"
  end
end
```

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to double-escape the newline characters:

```
{\"repeatEveryYear\":\"TRUE\",\"scheduleTime\":\"2010-09-09T16:11:46Z\",\"message\":\"Hello World\\n\\nFirst test\"}
```

This will convert each `\\` to `\` on the first pass (first decode) and then the `\n` to the newline on the 2nd pass (since it looks like it's a two-pass string).

Comment: Well then why is it only one of the double \n that gets eaten? Hm maybe, but how do I do this? I have tried with .gsub(/\n/, "\\n")

Comment: Just did some more testing. If I only have one \n in the json, like A\nB, it also gets removed and turned into a space so it becomes A B, but if I have A\n\nB it becomes A\nB??